# How can the names of chapters, tables, figures and contents be set?

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr

I'm writing a configuration for a template LaTeX document and I'm trying to write the configuration that defines the text used in titles of the document (such as the name used to indicate a chapter, a figure, a table etc.). How should this be done?

The way I've written the configuration (which should make it clear what I'm trying to do) is as follows:

```
\documentclass[american, a4paper]{report}

\input{configuration} % (contains code like: \edef\styleTitles{0})

% title style
    \ifcase\styleTitles
        % case 0
        \newcommand{\figureNameSpecification}{Figure}
        \newcommand{\tableNameSpecification}{Table}
        \newcommand{\contentsNameSpecification}{Contents}
        \newcommand{\chapterNameSpecification}{Chapter}
    \or
        % case 1
        \newcommand{\figureNameSpecification}{figure}
        \newcommand{\tableNameSpecification}{table}
        \newcommand{\contentsNameSpecification}{contents}
        \newcommand{\chapterNameSpecification}{chapter}
    \or
        % case 2
        \newcommand{\figureNameSpecification}{FIGURE}
        \newcommand{\tableNameSpecification}{TABLE}
        \newcommand{\contentsNameSpecification}{CONTENTS}
        \newcommand{\chapterNameSpecification}{CHAPTER}
    \fi
```

I'm not sure about what should come next. Something like the following seems promising, but it doesn't seem to change anything:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\chapterNameSpecification}
```

Previously, I used code like the following to set the style of the chapter names:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1 em}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

How should I set the various text titles of the document to those I define in my configuration?

Comment: Your example is of course not compilable and incomplete. If I cut it down to a working example, I get `CHAPTER` for example, if apply  `\def\styleTitle{2}`

Comment: Let' see:  \figurename. \tablename, \chaptername, \contentsname .

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: Looking at this again, this is a stupid way of doing stuff. The names stay the same in all instances, you the layout changes.